# how to add a cross domain header to node.js response

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, server, cors

So i have a major problem. I need to get data from a little node.js server that i built and then use that data. the problem that i am having is that the error says that i can't do cross domain requests and from what i have seen i need to add a header for that. i have seen many exampled of ways to fix this but they all use express. I am trying to stay away from express because i am in a sand-boxed host and there is not a way to add express.

--server code--

```
    var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url');
var tweets = {"tweets":[]};

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    query = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
    var response = {};
    //res.end(JSON.stringify(query));
    if(query.action){
      console.log("Moving on to phase two!");
      if(query.action === "read") {
          console.log("Listing off the posts");
          response = tweets;
      }
      else {
        if(query.action === "post"){
          if(query.message) {
            var tweet = {};
            tweet.message = query.message;
            tweets.tweets.push(tweet);
            response.stat = "All Good!";
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      response.error = "No Action";
    }
    response.url = req.url;
    res.write(JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    res.end();
}).listen();
```

--client function--

```
function getJSON(url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, false);
        xhr.send();
        return JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    }
```

I am hoping that it would be an easy fix that won't be to hard to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have figured out what i needed to do. I tryed running

```
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

and it worked! none of the other methods did anything except for error. thank you for trying to help me answer the question.

Comment: request from same host ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `res.header` to set the CORS header like below before sending the response back to client -

```
 res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // restrict it to the required domain
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');

  // Set custom headers for CORS
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-type,Accept,X-Access-Token,X-Key');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to enable CORS on your server.

if you use expressjs, there is a middleware for it call [cors](https://github.com/expressjs/cors). just use `app.use(require('cors'))` and you will be all set.